# JSON objects to Java Objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to get the fieldName value as list from the code using Java. using JSON parser I took the data of field as JsonArray but within the array i am unable to fetch the fieldName Values. Help me to do it.

```
{
"fluentMethods": true,
"relationships": [],
"fields": [
    {
        "fieldName": "streetAddress",
        "fieldType": "String"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "postalCode",
        "fieldType": "String"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "city",
        "fieldType": "String"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "stateProvince",
        "fieldType": "String"
    }
],
"changelogDate": "20170809051415",
"entityTableName": "location",
"dto": "no",
"pagination": "no",
"service": "no"
```

}

Comment: `try{JSONObject jsonObject = newJSONObject("YourResponceResult");
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("fields");
            for (int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){JSONObjectjsonObject1_filedvalues = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 String fieldName = jsonObject1_filedvalues.getString("fieldName");
  String fieldType = jsonObject1_filedvalues.getString("fieldType");    Log.d("FieldName","Fieldtype"+fieldName+" "+fieldType); }
        }catch (Exception e) { Log.d("printexeception",""+e.toString());}`

Comment: try this let me know @Mejari Chellapandian

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried it, its not working. JsonArray "fields" is not stored

Comment: did you checked log cat,,,,Post your code what you are tried.

Comment: Hae Gowthaman, Thanks a lot it worked..... Error with previous code

Comment: You are welcome .@ Mejari Chellapandian